# Call to a member function get()

Tags: zend-framework2

I created a sort base module in my ZF2 vendor library.  So far everything is working the way I want it to work.  I do have a problem.  While I am able to extend the base module's controllers, I am unable to access the base service.  I am using Doctrine 2 as my database layer.

After implementing the ServiceLocator, I am getting Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in my base service file. My BaseService file is shown as below:

```
namespace MyResource\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class BaseService implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * Entity manager instance
     *
     * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    protected $_em;

    protected $_serviceLocator;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->getEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an instance of the Doctrine entity manager loaded from the service
     * locator
     *
     * @return Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        if (null === $this->_em) {
            $this->_em = $this->getServiceLocator()
                 ->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        }
        return $this->_em;
    }

    /**
     * Set serviceManager instance
     *
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return void
     */
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve serviceManager instance
     *
     * @return ServiceLocatorInterface
     */
    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you call/create your service from the ServiceManager before using it ?

Answer (score 0):

1):

Your property is called

```
protected $_serviceLocator;
```

but you are assigning your values to

```
protected $serviceLocator;
```

2)

Are you creating your Service via DI or the service manager? If you do then the ServiceLocator should be automatically injected for you, if you are creating it manually using the "new" keyword then it will not have the ServiceLocatior attached.

Answer (score 0):

> There seems to be a glitch in ZF2 .If you try setting the properties
>   as below the problem will be fixed. Try like this

```
foreach ($resultSet as $row) {

        $entity = new Countrypages();
            $entity->setId($row->id);
        $entity->setName($row->name);
        $entity->setSnippet($row->snippet);
        $entity->setSortorder($row->sortorder);
        $entity->setActive($row->active);
        $entity->setCreated($row->created);
        $entity->setModified($row->modified);
        $entity->setFirstname($row->firstname);
        $entity->setCreatedby($row->createdby);
        $entities[] = $entity;
    }
```

> ignore this

```
  foreach ($resultSet as $row) {

                    $entity = new Countrypages();
                    $entity->setId($row->id);
                    ->setName($row->name);
                    ->setSnippet($row->snippet);
                    ->setSortorder($row->sortorder);
                    ->setActive($row->active);
                    ->setCreated($row->created);
                    ->setModified($row->modified);
                    ->setFirstname($row->firstname);
                    ->setCreatedby($row->createdby);
                    $entities[] = $entity;
                }
```

> I hope this help you save your time.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `use use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManagerAwareInterface` but you're implementing `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` (and there's no "use" statement for that one).